# If I know the length of a string, should I declare it as a char with specific length

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework

I'm preparing an Entity Framework model (CODE FIRST) for my C#.NET project. It dawned on me that I was going to have PageTitles stored as strings which have no length restrictions apart from the max and minimum bits available.

I have assumed that if I know a string will be 255 characters long and never exceed that, I could declare my string as a new char[255].

What are the downsides of using char instead of string.
What are the upsides of using char instead of string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContentManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class Page
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string PageTitle { get; set; }
        // This seems wasteful and unclear     

        char[] PageTitle = new char[255]; 
        // How would i apply { get; set; } to this?
    }
}
```

Is there some way of restricting a strings size?

---------------ANSWERED---------------------

This is now my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ContentManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class Page
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }        
        [MaxLength(255)] public string Title { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*, Donald Knuth.

Comment: oh damienG is paying more attention then I am. Are you using code first? if not i'll remove my answer.

Comment: Yes, code first. And the [ MaxLength(255) ] is probably what I am looking for.

Comment: k, maybe you should add that to your question. it might help others looking for the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As DamienG pointed out, this will only work in case of code first.

Are you looking for this?

```
[MaxLength(255)]
public string PageTitle { get; set; }
```

Referenced dll:
**Assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll**

Referenced namespace:
`namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: That will only work for Code First. If you're using the designer it will be ignored.

Comment: Looking good. Out of interest. I've never been sure how these [] paramaters are executed. Any chance you could enlighten me on how these property bits and bobs work (tech terminology)? (ill mark this as answer when it allows me)

Comment: They are called attributes and all the compiler does is add them as metadata. At runtime interested code (like Code First) uses Reflection to find and interpret what they mean in their own context.

Comment: What header/namespace/class extension do I need to put in to use MaxLength property?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: :) Thanks. Working like a charm!

Comment: good stuff :). good luck / have fun on the rest of your adventure

Answer (score 6):

No, you should not use a `char[]` when you intend to operate on it as a string.  Why?  Beacuse `string` has a ton of useful methods that will be unavailable to you if you use a character array.  Performance benefits of a character array, if any, would be exceedingly minimal.

Comment: Likely of more importance is that a `char[]` is mutable, a `string` is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't store strings as chars as you'll be forever cursing as you pass them around to things that want a string.

You can specify a maximum length for a string in Entity Framework using the designer for model-first or using the MaxLength attribute on the property for Code First models.

Answer (score 0):

Use the StringLength attribute to inform the framework about the maximum length.  You can continue to use strings instead of character arrays.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
...
[StringLength(255)]
public string PageTitle { get; set; }
```

Using the StringLength attribute in this case may be preferable to the MaxLength attribute because StringLength can also used by the model validation framework to validate user input.

Comment: What's the difference between stringlength and maxlength :D ? I could google but I may never get to hear your awesome explanation

Answer (score 0):

If basic inconvenience is note enough to convince you not to do so - it is also against API design guidelines for C#/.Net - returning arrays via get/set methods is not recommended due to unclear behavior (is it copy/reference) and potential performance impact due to copying large arrays.

When you re-read your sample code you will already know the answer - it is bad idea to replace `string` with `char[255]` in public API because it will be very hard to deal with - you don't know how to set it. Most people will expect "XxxxxTitle" property to be be of any type `string`.

If you need to put length restriction - just enforce it in `set` method.